# Capture screenshot of all the elements present on a page

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, screenshot, bufferedimage

I'm trying to capture the screenshot of all the elements present on a webpage and want to store it in my disk for which i have written the below code.

The only issue is this piece of code is working only for the first iteration and after which some unexpected thing is happening.

```
List<WebElement> eleId = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@id]")); //fetch all the elements with ID attribute
    System.out.println(eleId.size());

    for (int i = 0;i < eleId.size();i++) {

//          Get entire page screenshot
            File screenshot = ((TakesScreenshot) driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
            BufferedImage fullImg = ImageIO.read(screenshot);

//          Get the location of element on the page
            Point point = eleId.get(i).getLocation();

//          Get width and height of the element
            int eleWidth = eleId.get(i).getSize().getWidth();
            int eleHeight = eleId.get(i).getSize().getHeight();

//          Crop the entire page screenshot to get only element screenshot
            BufferedImage eleScreenshot = fullImg.getSubimage(point.getX(), point.getY(), eleWidth, eleHeight);
            ImageIO.write(eleScreenshot, "png", screenshot);

//          Creating variables name for image to be stores in the disk
            String fileName = eleId.get(i).getAttribute("id");
            String imageLocation = "D:\\" + fileName + ".png";
//          System.out.println(imageLocation);

//          Copy the element screenshot to disk
            File screenshotLocation = new File(imageLocation);
            FileUtils.copyFile(screenshot, screenshotLocation);

            System.out.println("Screenshot has been stored.");
}
```

Comment: what do you mean by unexpected things? is you script throws any error?

Comment: It is not throwing any error but running only for one iteration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi Sandeep try below code. It is working for me. I just added one "if" condition to check the image height and width.

```
@Test(enabled=true)
public void getIndividualElementScreenShot() throws IOException{
    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.get("http://www.google.com/");
    driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    List<WebElement> eles = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@id]"));
    System.out.println(eles.size());
    for(WebElement ele : eles){
        //Get Entire page screen shot
        File screenShot = ((TakesScreenshot)driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
        BufferedImage fullImage = ImageIO.read(screenShot);

        //Get the location on the page
        Point point = ele.getLocation();

        //Get width and height of an element
        int eleWidth = ele.getSize().getWidth();
        int eleHeight = ele.getSize().getHeight();

        //Cropping the entire page screen shot to have only element screen shot
        if(eleWidth != 0 && eleHeight != 0){
            BufferedImage eleScreenShot = fullImage.getSubimage(point.getX(), point.getY(), eleWidth, eleHeight);
            ImageIO.write(eleScreenShot, "png", screenShot);


            //Creating variable name for image to be store in disk
            String fileName = ele.getAttribute("id");
            String imageLocation = "F:\\ElementImage\\"+fileName+".png";
            System.out.println(imageLocation);

            //Copy the element screenshot to disk
            File screenShotLocation = new File(imageLocation);
            org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.copyFile(screenShot, screenShotLocation);

            System.out.println("Screen shot has beed stored");

        }
    }
    driver.close();
    driver.quit();
}
```

Comment: Ty @Sandipan Pramanik, i think the issue was with the width and height of the element i was trying to access...tysm :)

Answer (score 0):

Your code is doing fine. But you are overwriting the file in each iteration. Did you get it? Change file name in each iteration by assigning new file name in fileName variable. Use the code below:

```
        List<WebElement> eleId = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@id]")); //fetch all the elements with ID attribute
        System.out.println(eleId.size());

        for (int i = 0;i < eleId.size();i++) {

//            Get entire page screenshot
                File screenshot = ((TakesScreenshot)driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
                BufferedImage fullImg = ImageIO.read(screenshot);

//            Get the location of element on the page
                Point point = eleId.get(i).getLocation();

//            Get width and height of the element
                int eleWidth = eleId.get(i).getSize().getWidth();
                int eleHeight = eleId.get(i).getSize().getHeight();

//            Crop the entire page screenshot to get only element screenshot
                BufferedImage eleScreenshot = fullImg.getSubimage(point.getX(), point.getY(), eleWidth, eleHeight);
                ImageIO.write(eleScreenshot, "png", screenshot);

//            Creating variables name for image to be stores in the disk
                String fileName = eleId.get(i).getAttribute("id");
                String imageLocation = "D:/" + fileName + i + ".png";
//            System.out.println(imageLocation);

//            Copy the element screenshot to disk
                File screenshotLocation = new File(imageLocation);
                FileUtils.copyFile(screenshot, screenshotLocation);

                System.out.println("Screenshot has been stored.");
    }
```

Comment: i tried this as well, but still the same output, it is stopping after first iteration.

Comment: Copy & Paste the code portion from the edited answer. I think, this will help. :)

Comment: Tried copy paste as well..but only one iteration.

Comment: Then you have only one element with this path locator. It works fine for multiple elements in the page. Hope that, you got it.

Comment: You may check it again by replacing your code with the provided one. Let me know whether it works. I think ,it should. I've tested it myself.